# How do I add custom formatters for rivets in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, rivets.js

I'm trying to add a couple of custom formatters, but I keep getting this error.

> [ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Object' has no index signature.

This is how I'm registering my custom formatters.

```
rivets.formatters['fromNow'] = (value: number, now: number): string => {
    return humanizeDuration((now - value) * 1000);
};
```

For the record, I am using `noImplicitAny` set to `true` in my `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Have you installed the types required for `rivets.js`?

Comment: Yes. I've added @types/rivets to my project.

Comment: I managed to get my code working by including my custom version of the @types/rivets type definition. I replaced ``formatters: Object`` with ``formatters: { [key: string]: any }`` and that allowed me to add my custom formatters.

Comment: If you have `@types/rivets` then ideally you should not have to write custom typings.

Comment: I replaced ``@types/rivets`` with my own version. I don't have them both installed at the same time.